# Renaming Files with Mathematica

Tags: files-and-directories

I have a lot of video and text files. They all have the name: "Number-Suómething"

So for instance:

> 02-2.2-raKfcgvtavU.mp4

Is it possible to batch rename all the files using Mathematica to only "Number" ?

So for instance:

> 02.mp4

Comment: I think it possible. Functions like `FileNames`, `FileBaseName` and `NotebookDirectory` might be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following method does not require a **specific fixed** number of digits in the start of file name and does not depend on **specific fixed** non-numeric separator such as "-".

```
rename[name_]:=
RenameFile[
    name,
    StringCases[name,(x:DigitCharacter..)~~___~~".mp4":>x<>".mp4"][[1]]
]
```

1) **Back up your files**, - better make a new working copy of your directory.

2) Point Wolfram Language to that directory:

```
SetDirectory["path to your directory"]
```

3) Rename files:

```
rename /@ FileNames[]
```

You can also use **`CopyFile` instead of `RenameFile`** in order to keep the original file and place the renamed file in a directory of your choice. Because `CopyFile` can copy and rename simultaneously.

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Simple
Just set the current working directory to the folder which contains the files:

```
SetDirectory["C\\…"]
```

And then execute this command:

```
RenameFile[#, StringTake[ToString[#] , 2] <> ".mp4"] & /@ 
 FileNames["*.mp4"]
```

For .txt just do the same but replace the ".mp4" with ".txt"

**Copy-Paste Code:**

```
 SetDirectory["C\\…"]
 RenameFile[#, StringTake[ToString[#] , 2] <> ".mp4"] & /@ 
     FileNames["*.mp4"]
 RenameFile[#, StringTake[ToString[#] , 2] <> ".txt"] & /@ 
     FileNames["*.txt"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to map the following function over a list of full file names (with their full path). *Use at your own risk.*

```
rename = file \[Function] RenameFile[
   file,
   FileNameJoin[
    {
     DirectoryName[file],
     StringSplit[FileBaseName[file], "-"][[1]] <> "." <> FileExtension[file]
     }
    ]
   ]
```

For example, you can find all files with extension `"*.mp4"` in a given path `path` with

```
FileNames[FileNameJoin[{path, "*.mp4"}]]
```